# Product of dual norms in $\mathbb R^n$ inequality

Tags: inequality, normed-spaces, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Suppose $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$, do we have that $\|x\|_1 \|x\|_\infty \leq \|x\|_2^2$?

I came across this inequality as an intermediate step in proving something else, and it appears to me that it might be true. I could not find a counterexample on simple examples and simulations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the inequality you are trying to prove is false. Take, for example, $x=[1\:2\:3]\in\mathbb R^3$. Then: $\|x\|_1=1+2+3=6$, $\|x\|_\infty=3$ and $\|x\|^2_2=1^2+2^2+3^2=14$, so that: $18=\|x\|_1\|x\|_\infty\nleq\|x\|^2_2=14$.
What is **true** is the reversed inequality:
$$\|x\|^2_2\leq\|x\|_1\|x\|_\infty$$
This is the [Holder's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality) with $p=1$ and $q=\infty$. It's quite straightforward to prove, since:
$$\|x\|^2_2=\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|^2\leq\max_{i=1,\ldots,n}|x_i|\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|=\|x\|_\infty\|x\|_1$$
But we can observe that the inequality in your statement is true if we multiply $\|x\|^2_2$ by a constant. More precisely:
$$\|x\|_1\|x\|_\infty\leq \frac{1+\sqrt{n}}{2}\|x\|^2_2$$
You can read a complete proof of this fact [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3411767/prove-that-v-1-v-infty-leq-frac1-sqrtn2-v-2-2?noredirect=1).